# How to validate age in JavaScript with input date type

Tags: javascript, html

So I made an input `type="date"` but was unable to validate if the user entered a valid age (18+ yrs old).

How can I make it validate?

Sample code:

HTML:

```html
<label>
  Birthdate:
  <br />
  <input type="date" id="birthdate" placeholder="Enter birthdate" />
  <br />
  <span class="notif" id="bday"></span>
</label>
```

JS:

```js
var birth = document.getElementById('birthdate').value;
if (birth == '') {
  document.getElementById('bday').innerHTML = 'Please enter birthdate.';
}
```

I can only validate if there is no user input. I want it to store an error in `notif` if the age is under 18 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min/max attribute of the date input that is natively provided by HTML5. Check out this link for more information on the same - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can check differnce between their birthday date and today's date :

```
var their_date = new Date(2010, 6, 17);
var today = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth()+1,today.getDate());
var diff = new Date(date2.getTime() - their_date.getTime());
console.log(diff.getUTCFullYear() - 1970); // Gives difference as year
```